# How stressful was life when we lived in small tribes, in comparison to today?

Tags: stress

When comparing the stress level of today's life to earlier times, intuition may say: The world is so much more complex today, of course, it's more stressful now. But there is certainly a bias in the intuition.

Are there any estimations on how "hard" or stressful life was when we lived in small tribes, compared to today in a city?